# How to generate Android app bundle in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I used the official documentation of React Native to build apk file. All other procedures worked fine but creating aab file is not working for me. I used the following command 
cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease
But it's not working on Windows. It is just giving me error of ". is not recognized"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

to create main js Bundle

```js
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

and then run cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: The first command ran successfully and it generated index.android.bundle file. But on running the command cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease , it goes to android folder but gives error '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: ".\"' try with this, because in windows sometimes instead of this /, \ this works

Comment: For react-native versions 0.57 and above the bundle output path should be: `android/app/build/generated/assets/react/debug/index.android.js` See [react-native cli documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/commands.md#--bundle-output-string) for more details.

Comment: This gives me an APK file, not an AAB file.

Comment: for aab file, use command cd android && ./grdlew bundleRelease

Comment: @NeelamSoni, small typo in the command. Should be `gradlew`, not `grdlew`.

Answer (score 14):

```
cd android/
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 7):

Below command work perfectly in mac

```sh
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle && cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use the gradlew executable made **for Bash**, unless you install WSL for Windows (which is highly recommended for many other reasons, so then your ./gradlew would just work in the WSL shell). Without WSL, you need to use the `gradlew.bat` file instead, which should be in your android folder in your repo as its included in the react native starter files.

From then on, every command you see written with `./gradlew` should be replaced with it, e.g. `gradlew.bat assembleRelease`. Be sure to be in the 'android' folder though.